# <p v-text="foo"> vs <p>{{foo}}</p> in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, mustache

what is the difference between `<p v-text="foo">` and `<p>{{ foo }}</p>` in vue?

I know `{{ foo }}` is some DOM thingy, but they achieve the same function, so is `<p v-text="foo">` also doing something to DOM?

Comment: `{{}}` interpolations have nothing to do with the dom. They are parsed internally by the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing.  From the `v-text` [docs](https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-text):

> Internally, {{ Mustache }} interpolations are also compiled as a v-text directive on a textNode.

With either one, the compiler will turn the template markup into the same node.

Answer (score 1):

Another subtle difference which may yield unexpected results depending on your use-case is the [Line breaks on a single-line element](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/singleline-html-element-content-newline.html) rule. Consider the example snippets below:

**Sample 1**

```
<template>
  <ul class="some-items">
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
...
const someItems = ['Snap', 'Crackle', 'Pop']
...
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
.some-items {
  li {
    display:inline;

    &:after {
      content: ', ';
    }

    &:last-child:after {
      content: '.';
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

**Sample 2**

```
<template>
  <ul class="some-items">
    <li
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
...
const someItems = ['Snap', 'Crackle', 'Pop']
...
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
.some-items {
  li {
    display:inline;

    &:after {
      content: ', ';
    }

    &:last-child:after {
      content: '.';
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

**Sample 3**

```
<template>
  <ul class="some-items">
    <li
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item"
      v-text="item"
    />
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
...
const someItems = ['Snap', 'Crackle', 'Pop']
...
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
.some-items {
  li {
    display:inline;

    &:after {
      content: ', ';
    }

    &:last-child:after {
      content: '.';
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

It's very easy to assume that the displayed results will be the same on all three samples, however:

- **Sample 1**: Violates the above rule, even though it looks shorter, but is considered **bad**

  - **Result**: `Snap, Crackle, Pop.`
- **Sample 2**: Is considered good, but has white space between the tags

  - **Result**: `Snap , Crackle , Pop.`
- **Sample 3**: Also obeys the rule and the resul is as expected

  - **Result**: `Snap, Crackle, Pop.`